# Remover todos os atributos do HTML

Tags: html, html5, visual-studio-code, notepad++

Tenho um arquivo de aproximadamente 60000 linhas e preciso remover todos os atributos do arquivo HTML.

Sabem o nome de alguma aplicação, plugin do notepad ou alguma forma para realizar esse processo de forma automatizada?
Desde já agradeço!

```
Exemplo:
<td height="20" align="left"><font color="#000000">Abono</font></td>

COMO DEVERIA FICAR:
<td >Abono</td>
```

Comment: Para deixar claro, o que você entende por atributo do HTML?

Comment: Com expressão regular vc deve conseguir. `string+=+"+tudo que vier depois das aspas+"` substitui por `' ' `

Answer (score 1):

Use essa expressão regular

```
<.*?>|</.*?>
```

E substitua por "nada"
Igual  na imagem  abaixo 
Aperte <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd>
para abrir o dialog

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obs: Lembre-se de marcar lá em baixo o campo  "expressão regular"

**Edit 1 ***
Como  você informou no comentario para remover os atributos da tag Use a expressão

```
<([a-z]+) .*?=".*?( *\/?>)
```

e substitua por

```
<\1$2
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja funcionando  [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/qK5uY3/3)

Atente-se caso estiver usando  aspas simples `'` subsititua no  regex as aspas duplas

> Fontes
>   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33066103/notepad-regular-expression-to-remove-html-tag-containing-embedded-tags

Comment: @Marcos.Brinner, obrigado pela sua ajuda!
Eu editei minha pergunta pra ter o exemplo exato do que preciso.
Consegue me ajudar melhor? Desculpe não ter realizado a pergunta de forma correta!

Comment: Fiz uma alteração  na resposta veja

Comment: @Marcos.Brinner, ainda persiste a tag <font> </font>.
Poderia me explicar, por gentileza, o que significam esses códigos?

Comment: ficou  apenas essas tags de font ? basta subistituir elas nesse mesmo local, porem marque a  opição  "normal" lá em  baixo